# Add inverted commas as text in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an AppleScript where you change your Mac's local hostname. I'm trying to do it through a terminal command, but if the user wants spaces in the hostname, It doesn't work, as for the command with spaces to work, you need inverted commas, and as far as I'm aware of, you can't do add " as text in AppleScript. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
set computername to display dialog "Type the desired name" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Continue"} default button "Continue" as text
display dialog (text returned of computername) & " is this correct? " & "."

display dialog "If it askes you, please type your password in. (It may ask more than once)"

do shell script "scutil --set LocalHostName " & """ & (text returned of computername) & """

display dialog "Changes will be applied after a restart. Click continue to save changes and restart."

do shell script "shutdown -r now"
```

I need to enter " before the name is entered, as well as after.

```
 do shell script "scutil --set LocalHostName " & """ & (text returned of computername) & """
```

[but I just get errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5xFW.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're encouraged to convince the user not to use space characters in the host name. It's very error-prone to do so.

AppleScript provides a simple solution to handle escaping parameters in shell scripts properly:

```
do shell script "scutil --set LocalHostName " & quoted form of (text returned of computername)
```

Comment: It comes up with this error: SCPreferencesSetLocalHostName() failed: Invalid argument

Comment: @Charlie McMahon, From the `scutil` man page,  "The --set option requires super-user access.", so the `do shell script` _command_ needs to be run with `administrator privileges`, e.g. `do shell script "scutil --set LocalHostName " & quoted form of (text returned of computer name) with administrator privileges`

Comment: The error is this: SCPreferencesSetLocalHostName() failed: Invalid argument

Comment: The error is not related to the question how to escape parameters containing space characters.